# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException in AjaxControlToolkit

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am getting error as below, I am not able to understand it. Please help me to solve this problem.

**Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:**

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Property accessor
>   'Rating' on object 'AjaxControlToolkit.RatingExtender' threw the
>   following exception:'Input string was not in a correct format.

I just came to know about error :

```
$("#showrating").append($("#rtng1").clone())
```

when i removed the above line from all code, that error vanished. what is the wrong with this code ?

**Asp.net code**

```
<div id="rtng1" style="display: none;">
<div style="font-weight: bold; margin-top: 10px;">
Rating :
<div style="margin-left: 57px; margin-top: -18px;">
<cc1:Rating ID="rtng" runat="server" BehaviorID="rating" StarCssClass="StarCss" FilledStarCssClass="FilledStarCss" EmptyStarCssClass="EmptyStarCss" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStarCss">
</cc1:Rating>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Script part for type text/html :**

```
$("#showrating").append($("#rtng1").clone());
$('#rtng1').attr("style", "display:block;");
```

Comment: Please show your code which throws this exception..

Comment: there is very long code. And it was working fine, dnt know how this error occur. can you tell me which part contain this error so that i can show you some code.

Comment: show us your code part

Comment: from your error code i can gurss you are passing input sting in a wrong format.

Comment: put your asp code as well

Comment: check question again...